# Botón seleccionable o no según el valor de Firebase

Tags: java, android

Tengo un `button` y con `btn1.setEnabled(true);` puedo hacer que sea o no seleccionable, pero quiero que *true* o *false* lo obtenga de mi `database`

En *Firebase* lo tengo así:

> check: true

y el código en mi `Activity`

```
    et1 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.et1);
    btn1 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn1);
    btn1check = new TextView(MainActivity.this);

    firebaseDatabase=FirebaseDatabase.getInstance();
    databaseReference=firebaseDatabase.getReference();

    databaseReference.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
            Map<String, String> data = (Map<String, String>) dataSnapshot.getValue();
            // aquí obtengo el valor true o false de "check"
            btn1check.equals(data.get("check"));
            // obtengo el valor de btn1check, si es "true" es seleccionable, si es "false", no
            btn1.setEnabled(Boolean.parseBoolean(btn1check.getText().toString()));
        }

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

        }
    });
```

El problema es que nunca es seleccionable el `button` al abrir la `Activity`

Comment: Pero que valor tiene tu TextView btn1check ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Podrias intentar hacer el parseo asi

```
boolean isEnabled = Boolean.parseBoolean(data.get("check"));
```

o tambien puedes hacerlo :

```
Boolean isEnabled = Boolean.valueOf(data.get("check"));
btn1.setEnabled(isEnabled);
```

Tambien seria interesante que verificas siempre el valor del string `check` para evitar errores de datos

```
string check = data.get("check");
if (check.equalsIgnoreCase("true") || check.equalsIgnoreCase("false")) {
    Boolean isEnabled = Boolean.valueOf(check);
    btn1.setEnabled(isEnabled);
}else {
    //evaluas que hacer
}
```

Comment: Recibo esto al compilar `Error:(48, 47) error: incompatible types: String cannot be converted to Boolean`

Comment: Actualice mi respuesta, era erronea la manera en que intentaba hacer la conversion, te deje dos formas de hacerlo

Comment: Funciona, pero tengo un problema y es que en el valor de la db tengo que escribir *true* pero entre "".

Comment: y cual es el problema? si viene el texto true entre "", funcionara bien la verificacion del texto

Answer (score 1):

Recuerda que al usar  `Boolean.parseBoolean(variable)` se obtendría un valor true si variable tiene  el valor de "true", en cualquier otro caso tendrá el valor "false", ejemplo:

```
    String a = "true";
    String b = "false";
    String c = "1";
    String d = "0";
    String e = "";
    String f = null;
    String g = "check: true";
    String h = "valor true;
```

**al convertir los valores de `String` anteriores, únicamente el primero tendría un valor `true`** al ser convertido mediante:

```
boolean valor = Boolean.parseBoolean(a)
```

---

Si el valor de `btn1check.getText().toString()` es "check: true" y deseas que cuando tenga este valor se active el botón puedes realizar esto:

```
btn1.setEnabled((btn1check.getText().toString().indexOf("true")>-1)?true:false);
```

de esta forma habilitará tu botón si en el texto del TextView btn1check encuentra el texto "true".

Comment: Pero no quiero las "", es decir escribir solamente en el valor *true*

Comment: Deseas que a partir del texto definido en btn1check se active o desactive el botón btn1, esto si en el btn1check dice "true"?

Comment: Exacto! @Jorgesys pero he decidido mejor saltarme el paso de "btn1check" y borrarlo, es decir, que se active cuando ponga true sin comillas y si es false sin comillas se desactive en "check"

Comment: buen si deseas lo primero puede realizarse con esto: btn1.setEnabled((btn1check.getText().toString().indexOf("true")>-1)?true:false);  de otra forma solo asegura que tenga el texto  "true" y con eso al parsearlo a boolean funcionara.